# "Image Processing"

Tags: dft, image-processing, image-compression, gnuradio

I'm an Italian student. I'm studying Gnu Radio and I would like to upload a photo, can I upload it with "file image source" or other blocks?
I need to make FFT of an a image. -> image 2D

Thank you very much
and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "upload a photo"? Also, have you considered asking this in GnuRadio's email support list? You may be able to get better answers there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably best to ask on the GNURadio forum.